# How to display specific cell values while using a dictionary in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I am slightly new to dictionary usage so appreciate any help extended in this area
I have employee related details in an excel sheet. i.e Col A to Col BD. The key created is a combination of Name, Dept and Grade.
I need to display various attributes of the employee such as DOJ, Training undertaken etc when user selects the employee displayed in the combo box of the Form.
I have managed to create the key in the dictionary. If i read a particular row(no) as Value and Key as the above combination how do i then display specific attributes of the employee selected. Listbox displays the same combination as the key created i.e Name, Dept and Grade

Any ideas suggestions on this is appreciated

I have done this using arrays but when the size of the range increases array search slows down the overall performance Hence was looking at using dictionary

`varArray_TP` is the array which contains all the data. A Listbox displays Name, Grade and Dept of the employee. This combination is stored in the array with `|` as the separator. When user selects an option from the listbox this is checked against the key in the array to display other attributes from the array.

```
' loading the data into the array
For i = 1 To TotalRows_TP
  For j = 1 To TotalCols_TP
   varArray_TP(i, j) = Sheets("TP").Cells(i + 1, j).Value
  Next j
Next i

' generating the key for each row in the array
For i = 1 To TotalRows_TP
  varArray_TP(i, TotalCols_TP + 1) = 
    WorksheetFunction.Concat( _
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TP").Range("C" & i + 1).Value, "|", _
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TP").Range("D" & i + 1).Value, "|", _
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TP").Range("AP" & i + 1).Value _
   )
Next i

' find the data based on the selected key
Sub Profile_Details()
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim j As Integer
  With UserForm1
    If .vLB_SearchValues.ListIndex > -1 And .vRb_ByName.Value = True Then
      For i = 1 To TotalRows_TP

        If varArray_TP(i, TotalCols_TP + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Concat( _
          .vLB_SearchValues.List(.vLB_SearchValues.ListIndex, 0), "|", _
          .vLB_SearchValues.List(.vLB_SearchValues.ListIndex, 1), "|", _
          .vLB_SearchValues.List(.vLB_SearchValues.ListIndex, 2) _
        ) Then

          .vLB_Grade.Caption = varArray_TP(i, 4)
          .vLB_PositionTitle.Caption = varArray_TP(i, 33)
          .vLB_Dateentered_JobGrade.Caption = varArray_TP(i, 7)
          .vLB_PersonnelArea.Caption = varArray_TP(i, 42)
          .vLB_Dateentered_Position.Caption = varArray_TP(i, 6)
          .vLB_BizRating.Caption = varArray_TP(i, 25)
          .vLB_PplRating.Caption = varArray_TP(i, 26)
          .vLB_UltimatePotential.Caption = varArray_TP(i, 10)
          .vLB_Name.Caption = varArray_TP(i, 3)
          UserForm2.vLB_TalentNaForm2.Caption = "Talent Name : " & .vLB_Name.Caption

        End If
      Next i
    End If

  End With
End Sub
```

Pasted below is the sample data table (tab separated):

```
User ID Name - LFM  Job Grade   Comp Grade  Date Entered Position   Date Entered Job Grade  Personnel   Area
T22MXIQ  Pillay Avinash 8   07  7-1-2015    7-1-2015    PU03 - JD   India Technology Center
B19CXIV Baishali    08  07  7-1-2015    7-1-2015    PU03 - JD   India Technology Center
B22MXIR Bhargavi    08  07  7-1-2015    7-1-2015    PU03 - JD   India Technology Center
T22MXIG Ghosh Anurag    09  07  7-1-2015    7-1-2015    PU03 - JD   India Technology Center
PU00177 Kadam Ashok 08  07  7-1-2015    7-1-2015    PU03 - JD   India Technology Center
PU00178 Kadam Sushma    03  07  7-1-2015    7-1-2015    PU03 - JD   India Technology Center
PU00180 Kadam Sushma    08  07  7-1-2015    7-1-2015    PU03 - JD   India Technology Center
M22MXIL Mugdha  08  07  7-1-2015    7-1-2015    PU03 - JD   India Technology Center
PU00179 Pandey Shobha   06  07  7-1-2015    7-1-2015    PU03 - JD   India Technology Center
T22MXIS Sanjyot 03  07  7-1-2014    7-1-2018    PU02 - JD   China Technology Center
T22MXIP Shah Pradnesh   07  07  7-1-2015    7-1-2015    PU03 - JD   India Technology Center
T22MXPS Shah Pradnesh   06  07  7-1-2015    7-1-2015    PU03 - JD   India Technology Center
T22MXUS Sushma  03  07  7-1-2015    7-1-2015    PU03 - JD   India Technology Center
T22MXVI Vrushali    08  08  7-1-2015    7-1-2015    PU02 - JD   China Technology Center
```

I need to show only the list of employees that match the name typed in the textbox using a string search so I used the below code. In case you have a better approach it would be welcome as I am still looping through the keys so I am guessing if there is an optimum search ability where i do not loop through the keys multiple times

```
str = UserForm1.vTB_SearchString.Text
  UserForm1.vLB_SearchValues.Clear

  With UserForm1
  If .vRb_ByName.Value = True Then
  UserForm1.vLB_SearchValues.ColumnWidths = "2.2 in; 0.5 in; 2.8 in"

For Each EmpKey In EmployeeDict.Keys
 EmpParts = Split(EmpKey, "|")
    If InStr(1, EmpParts(0), str, vbTextCompare) Then
    .vLB_SearchValues.AddItem
    .vLB_SearchValues.List(.vLB_SearchValues.ListCount - 1, 0) = EmpParts(0)
    .vLB_SearchValues.List(.vLB_SearchValues.ListCount - 1, 1) = EmpParts(1)
    .vLB_SearchValues.List(.vLB_SearchValues.ListCount - 1, 2) = EmpParts(2)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/

Comment: A Dictionary is designed to return a value for a given unique key; if you request the value of a non-existent key, you'll get an error. I can see using a Dictionary in one of two ways: loading the values from each row into the Dictionary itself using the Name / Dept / Grade key, and retrieving the data from the Dictionary using the selected key. Alternatively, you might add a unique number to each row in your Excel data, and use that unique number as the value of your Dictionary; once the user has selected an item from the combobox, you can use the composite key to get back the value, ...

Comment: ... which you can then use to read the various attributes from the Excel data. // Note: you're assuming the combination of Name Dept and Grade is always unique, which may or may not be a valid assumption. // RE: _I have done this using arrays_ I would strongly suggest you include some code that shows your current usage of arrays, in order to see how a Dictionary might be used instead. Also, keep in mind that any interaction with Excel objects -- worksheets, cells, ranges -- is liable to be a bigger bottleneck than just the use of arrays; seeing the code might allow answers to help with that.

Comment: Would like to share the sample code file with you. How do i send it across as its a big file

Comment: It's not much of a sample if it's so large. I would suggest you create a small data sample, with 5 rows of data, and no more than 6 columns for those 5 rows -- Name, Dept and Grade columns, and perhaps three other columns of data. Then, go to https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables and paste that sample data into the site; this will generate a text table you can paste into your question. Once you've done that, take the minimum amount of code that shows how you are currently using the array -- loading data from the spreadsheet, loading the data into the combobox, finding the record once ...

Comment: ... the user has selected something from the combobox; then paste that code into the question. (NB In general, if you want a user to be notified about your comment, enter their username with an `@` in your comment, e.g. `@ZevSpitz`.)

Comment: @ZevSpitz. Have added details of the code and sample data. Do let me know if you need further information

Comment: I face the issue when the employee data is increased to 5K or beyond. selection of employee and then displaying the attributes impacts performance. any suggestions on improving performance really helps.I am saving the data is an array and I compare the array values with selection in listbox. since the performance starts getting impacting i was thinking of moving to dictionary..@ZevSpitz

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use a Dictionary here, and I would even go so far as to say you should. Not for performance (although a Dictionary is more performant), but because it's simpler by far to get back a value from a Dictionary than to loop over an array searching for a matching key.

But I would suggest the main cause of the performance issues is this: when you use Excel objects (worksheets, ranges, worksheet functions) and their properties and methods, it's generally orders of magnitude slower than using pure VBA alternatives. Specifically:

- Instead of loading the data by looping over the cells with `varArray_TP(i, j) = Sheets("TP").Cells(i + 1, j).Value` in a loop, the Excel Range object supports creating a 2-dimensional array directly:

  ```
  Dim varArray_TP As Variant
  varArray_TP = Sheets("TP").Range("R1C1:R" & TotalRows_TP & "C" & TotalCols_TP)
  ```

  Admittedly, the dimensions of this array are fixed based on the range size, and we won't have an additional column to store the key in the array; but if we use a Dictionary we shouldn't have to.
- Don't use `WorksheetFunction.Concat`. Instead, use the VBA string concatenation operator -- `&`. For example to generate the key for a given `row` number in the array:

  ```
  key = varArray_TP(row, 3) & "|" & varArray_TP(row, 4) & "|" & varArray_TP(row, 42)
  ```

The following code shows how to use a Dictionary. Add a reference to **Microsoft Scripting Runtime** from **Tools -> References...**. Then, define your dictionary in the same place you've defined the array:

```
Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
```

Then:

```
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = Sheets("TP")

' load data into array
Dim varArray_TP As Variant
varArray_TP = wks.Range( _
    wks.Cells(1, 1), _
    wks.Cells(TotalRows, TotalCols) _
)

' fill the dictionary
' the key for each entry will be the Name, Grade and Dept, separated by |
' the corresponding value will be the first index of that person's data within the array
Dim rows as Long
rows = UBound(varArray_TP, 1)
Dim row As Long, key As String
For row = 1 To rows
    key = varArray_TP(row, 3) & "|" & varArray_TP(row, 4) & "|" & varArray_TP(row, 42)
    dict(key) = row
Next
```

There's still a piece missing: how do you populate the listbox with the keys? You might do something like this:

```
Dim key As Variant
For Each key In dict.Keys
    Dim parts() As String
    parts = Split(key, "|")

    ' parts is now a 1-dimensional array, with the Name, Dept and Grade
    ' TODO fill the listbox with the individual parts

Next
```

Then, when you want to retrieve the details, you could do something like this:

```
' find the data based on the selected key
Sub Profile_Details()
    With UserForm1
        If .vLB_SearchValues.ListIndex > -1 And .vRb_ByName.Value = True Then
            Dim row As Long
            row = dict( _
                .vLB_SearchValues.List(.vLB_SearchValues.ListIndex, 0) & "|" & _
                .vLB_SearchValues.List(.vLB_SearchValues.ListIndex, 1) & "|" & _
                .vLB_SearchValues.List(.vLB_SearchValues.ListIndex, 2) _
            )

           .vLB_Grade.Caption = varArray_TP(row, 4)
           .vLB_PositionTitle.Caption = varArray_TP(row, 33)
           .vLB_Dateentered_JobGrade.Caption = varArray_TP(row, 7)
           .vLB_PersonnelArea.Caption = varArray_TP(row, 42)
           .vLB_Dateentered_Position.Caption = varArray_TP(row, 6)
           .vLB_BizRating.Caption = varArray_TP(row, 25)
           .vLB_PplRating.Caption = varArray_TP(row, 26)
           .vLB_UltimatePotential.Caption = varArray_TP(row, 10)
           .vLB_Name.Caption = varArray_TP(row, 3)
           UserForm2.vLB_TalentNaForm2.Caption = "Talent Name : " & .vLB_Name.Caption

        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

---

After having written all this, I realized you can do something simpler: you could store the row number in the listbox itself, as a hidden column, and use that number to extract data from the array. This would mean you don't need a dictionary.

---

For more information about Scripting.Dictionary, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object).

Comment: you are wonderful. This was really awesome. I was able to proceed only till creating a dictionary. but the first point i.e loading the entire range into an array instead of looping through was an eye opener. also the avoiding concat function and using & instead of never thought off. I loved the last solution of hiding the row number.. it will speed things up for me. But I will still use the dictionary option as I want to explore dictionary usage as personal learning..

Comment: :; Thanks once again

Comment: @SanjyotSalgarPatkar I've added a link to the Dictionary reference on the MS documentation site.

Comment: @SanjyotSalgarPatkar Was there some kind of error or other problem when creating the dictionary? Is there any other way I could improve this answer?

Comment: varArray_TP = Sheets("TP").Range("R1C1:R" & TotalRows_TP & "C" & TotalCols_TP)

Comment: varArray_TP = Sheets("TP").Range("R1C1:R" & TotalRows_TP & "C" & TotalCols_TP)  . This line throws an error i.e R1C1 style not being recognized

Comment: so I added Application.ReferenceStyle = r1c1 but still it throws runtime error

Comment: i think r1c1 is not being recognized

Comment: @SanjyotSalgarPatkar Try something like this: `Dim wks As Worksheet: Set wks = Sheets("TP"): varArray_TP = wks.Range(wks.Cells(1,1), wks.Cells(TotalRows, TotalCols))` If that works, I'll update the answer.

Comment: I tried the .Cells line and it worked. I looked up on the web and seems like the R1C1 style for reading ranges doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @SanjyotSalgarPatkar I've updated the answer. If there's any way you think I could improve the answer, please let me know.

Comment: I need to list down the name of the employees in the listbox using a string match kind of a search so I used

Comment: @SanjyotSalgarPatkar so you used ??